# Incementally (online) Training of Encog Simple Feed Forward Network

Tags: java, encog

Is there a way to provide the training examples out of a stream ony by one?

Online training from [encog site](http://www.heatonresearch.com/faq/5/3):

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {

        // Create a neural network, using the utility.
        BasicNetwork network = EncogUtility.simpleFeedForward(2, 2, 0, 1, false);
        network.reset();

        // Create training data.
        MLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XOR_INPUT, XOR_IDEAL);

        // Train the neural network.
        final Backpropagation train = new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet, 0.07, 0.02);
        train.setBatchSize(1);

        // Evaluate the neural network.
        EncogUtility.trainToError(train, 0.01);
        EncogUtility.evaluate(network, trainingSet);

        // Shut down Encog.
        Encog.getInstance().shutdown();
    }
```

But my problem is, I can not do this:

```
    final Backpropagation train = new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet, 0.07, 0.02);
    train.setBatchSize(1);
```

Since my training set is a stream - so I receive the examples one by one. I would have to make multiple Backpropagation train objects which is not useful. But there is a good reason the training data is a stream so I can not load the whole set into ram.

I would need something like

```
while (traningData.hasNext()) {
  train(traningData.next();
}
```